# DateTime вида yyyymmddthhmmssz перевести в time_t

Tags: c++

Как можно меньшей кровью, может есть уже готовые библиотеки? Причем, замечание: дата может быть до 1970 года. Вообще это дата рождения. Кто что посоветует?

Answer (score 1):

Я посоветую отказаться от типа time_t. И хотя в нём можно сохранять даты, предшествующие 1970 году (в виде отрицательных чисел), лучше этого никогда не делать. Тип сделан знаковым отнюдь не для того, чтобы хранить в нём отрицательные числа. Это нужно для другого. Функции, работающие со временем, удобно делать так, чтобы в случае успеха они возвращали время, а в случае неудачи - отрицательный код ошибки.

Comment: Если бы мог отказаться - сделал бы это давно.

Answer (score 1):

Такая библиотека есть. Стандартная libc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

// yyyymmddhhmmss
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  struct tm t;
  const char *p = "yyyymmddhhmmss";

  if (av[1]) {
    char buf[1024];
    if (sscanf(av[1],"%s",buf) != 1) {
    Err:;
      printf ("Invalid argument [%s]\n",av[1]);
      exit (1);
    }
    if (strlen(buf) != strlen(p))
      goto Err;

    strncpy(buf,av[1],4); buf[4] = 0;
    if ((t.tm_year = atoi(buf)) < 1)
      goto Err;
    t.tm_year -= 1900;

    strncpy(buf,av[1]+4,2); buf[2] = 0;
    if ((t.tm_mon = atoi(buf)) < 1 || t.tm_mon > 12)
      goto Err;
    t.tm_mon--;

    strncpy(buf,av[1]+6,2); buf[2] = 0;
    if ((t.tm_mday = atoi(buf)) < 1 || t.tm_mday > 31)
      goto Err;

    strncpy(buf,av[1]+8,2); buf[2] = 0;
    if ((t.tm_hour = atoi(buf)) < 0 || t.tm_hour > 23)
      goto Err;

    strncpy(buf,av[1]+10,2); buf[2] = 0;
    if ((t.tm_min = atoi(buf)) < 0 || t.tm_min > 59)
      goto Err;

    strncpy(buf,av[1]+12,2); buf[2] = 0;
    if ((t.tm_sec = atoi(buf)) < 0 || t.tm_sec > 59)
      goto Err;

    p = "Your";
  } else {
    t.tm_sec = 10;
    t.tm_min = 20;
    t.tm_hour = 11;
    t.tm_mday = 21;
    t.tm_mon = 0;
    t.tm_year = 59;

    p = "My";
  }

  time_t tt = mktime(&t);
  if ((long)tt == -1)
    goto Err;
  printf ("%s birthday: %s\n",p,ctime(&tt));

  exit (fflush(stdout) == EOF);
}
```

Разбор строки yyyymmdd... сделайте, как Вам больше нравитя, а в остальном IMHO понятно.

Comment: Правда следует отметить, что на 32-bit машине этот код работает для дат в диапазоне примерно от 1902 до 2038 годов.

Comment: @avp А еще, например, сфейлится вот [**в такой**][1] ситуации. Парсить время и даты, насколько мне известно - это очень сложная и нетривиальная задача.

[1]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/145857/

Comment: Да, а еще она не совсем правильно для февраля берет даты. Можно задать, например 31 и в ответе будет 3 марта.

Просто показал ТС mktime().

--

По поводу делать самому или искать. IMHO всегда сначала пробовать самому, если первоначальный вариант не доводится, тогда разбираться. Иначе успехов не будет.